# How to reset user password from the admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

In my website, I want to let the admins **reset** the password of any user.

With **reset** I mean exactly what the `password_reset` view does (under *contrib.auth*): Send a confirmation link to that user email.

How would be the best way of doing that? Is there an already app/snippet that does that?

**Edit:**

Let's suppose user *john* is an admin. What I want is to let *john* reset any user's password through the admin interface. For example, to reset *max* password, he will just go to the *max* user, and click on any link to reset his password.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I finally did was to add a custom `ModelAdmin`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ...
    def reset_password(self, request, user_id):
        if not self.has_change_permission(request):
            raise PermissionDenied
        user = get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=user_id)

        form = PasswordResetForm(data={'email': user.email})
        form.is_valid()

        form.save(email_template_name='my_template.html')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('..')

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(UserAdmin, self).get_urls()

        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^(\d+)/reset-password/$',
                     self.admin_site.admin_view(self.reset_password)
            ),
        )
        return my_urls + urls
```

and I also had to override the `change_form.html` template, like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block object-tools %}
    {% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
        <ul class="object-tools">
            {# You can also give a name to that pattern and refer to it below using 'url' #}
            <li><a href="reset-password/" class="historylink">Reset password</a></li>

            <li><a href="history/" class="historylink">{% trans "History" %}</a></li>
            {% if has_absolute_url %}
                <li><a href="../../../r/{{ content_type_id }}/{{ object_id }}/" class="viewsitelink">
                    {% trans "View on site" %}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif%}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Reset Password from admin in Django]

If you want a more detailed explanation, I [blogged about it](http://blog.omederos.com/posts/2012/05/15/reseting-users-passwords-from-the-admin-site/).

Comment: +1, it's good you put feedback. But please put a summary of it in yout answer's body, otherwise the post is not protected from your blog ends, plus it feels like traffic whoring.

Answer (score 2):

The passreset app just exposes the django views via urls.py, and adjusts the login template to show a "Forgot my password" link.

The built-in django password reset views and templates are meant for self-reset. I guess the reset form could be prepopulated with a different user's email address (in the query string) but you'd still need to make adjustments such as changing the email template - "You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account" is probably not what you want:

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html

Therefore you should expose the views at different URLs if you want to include self-reset as well.
Hook the django views into urls.py like so:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.auth.views', 
    url(r'^accounts/password/reset/$',
        'password_reset',
        name='password-reset'), 
    url(r'^accounts/password/reset/done/$',
        'password_reset_done',
        name='password-reset-done'), 
    url(r'^accounts/password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[-\w]+)/(?P<token>[-\w]+)/$',
        'password_reset_confirm',
        name='password-reset-confirm'), 
    url(r'^accounts/password/reset/complete/$',
        'views.password_reset_complete',
        name='password-reset-complete')
)
```

and where you want to make adjustments, pass in e.g. your own email template:

```
url(r'^/accounts/password/reset/$',
    'password_reset',
    {'email_template_name': 'my_templates/password_reset_email.html'}
    name='password-reset'),
```

The "password_reset" view has more parameters you can tweak:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.views
("post_reset_redirect" comes to mind as another one for your purposes)

To show a corresponding link you'd either change the User admin (careful, already registered - unregister then register your own, subclassed plus additional link field) or the change_form template itself.

I'm unaware of an app that provides this out-of-the-box, so I upvoted the question :-).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there is an app for that. Check here:

https://github.com/bendavis78/django-passreset

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself. What I want is to let admin reset passwords of **other** users, not to reset their own passwords if they forgot about them.

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by reset? You just want to change the password via admin or something else? How you will let the user know that his password was reset and how do you want him to set a new password?

Comment: He doesn't want to change the password (he can do that already) - he wants to invoke password reset as if he was that user. Incl. triggered email etc.

Comment: Ok. Than I don't really understand why the package I gave is a bad idea. It can be changed to accept the user from admin interface. I mean, you can add "reset password" link in the user's change_form.html in admin. The link will take the user name (from original template tag, for example) and pass it to django-passreset app.

Comment: @alexarsh something like that is what I finally did, but what I meant is that the app you provided doesn't do anything for me. All those views (with the reset-password logic) were already under `contrib.auth`. Check `password_reset` view in `django/contrib/auth/views.py`.